# Karp reduction from optimization problems to decision problems

Tags: np-complete, reductions, np, decision-problem, polynomial-time-reductions

When you consider Cook reductions, then decision and optimization versions of the problems are polynomial time reducible to each other.

Focusing on Cook reductions, there exists a natural Karp reduction from the decision version of a problem to optimization version. Is the converse also true?

Comment: NP-completeness is a category of decision problems. When we say that an optimization problem is NP-complete, what we really mean is that its decision version is NP-complete.

Comment: Thanks. Let me edit the question then removing the last part.

Comment: What do you mean by a Karp reduction from the optimization version to the decision version? Can you give a definition or an example?

Comment: Consider the problem of deciding whether there is vertex cover of size less than $\leq k$ and the problem of finding the minimum vertex cover.

Comment: You still haven't define what a Karp reduction would be in this context. I know what a Karp reduction is for two decision problems, but that's not the case you're interested in.

Comment: So my question does not make sense then. Ok, I see. Thank you very much.

Comment: Can I ask one more thing? How can we say that optimization versions of many problems are NP-Hard if we can not make a Karp reduction to optimization problems?

Comment: When we say that an optimization problem is NP-hard, what we really mean is that its decision version is NP-hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to comments by Yuval Filmus, I understand that my question does not make sense as Karp reductions are defined for decision problems. Since Cook reductions allow more freeness, it makes sense to talk about a Cook reduction from a decision problem to an optimization problem, but this is not true for Karp reduction.